# How to fit a serie of div's into the size of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of divs (ranging from 2 to 80) that are loaded into my html as inline-blocks.
The width of these divs are designed to fill up the entire space of the window width (like a single bar) minus the margins of the div `(data.length*2)` and minus the padding `-20` depending on a variable that's generated through `tag.duplicate_count/full_links.length`.

So far so good

```
var tag_width = tag.duplicate_count/full_links.length;
tag_width = ($(window).width()-(data.length*2)-20)*(tag_width);
```

Result:

|***_*_**|*|*__|__*_*__*_*_|__*_*|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*|

<--------------- window.width --------------->

The piece of code above actually works but here's where the problem starts. Some div's sometimes get a width assigned that's smaller then 10px. 
To fix this I've put this in my code:

```
tag_width = tag_width < 10 ? 10 : tag_width;
```

Result:

|***_*_**|__*|***_**|***_*__*_*___**|***_*__**|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

___|

<--------------- window.width --------------->

However the total width of all the divs combined gets larger then the width of the screen and it will start to make a second bar (WHICH I REALLY  DON'T WANT!). I know why but I want to prevent it. Is there anyone who can help with this problem, has encountered this problem or knows the answer?

Comment: How much larger becomes it?

Comment: all the (10-tag_width)'s you get from making the tag_width 10.

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more code? I'm having a hard time visualizing this issue :)

Comment: What's the problem with divs having smaller than 10px width?

Comment: It seems that since you are assigning a minimum size of 10px, all of the divs cannot fit on one line. They were fitting prior because there was no constraint

Comment: @skyline3000 because the div's have to be clickable.

Comment: @pbojinov I understand that, but how do I set the constraint on all the other divs that don't match that rule so that it will fit?

Comment: You obviously see the problem here... what type of solution are you looking for? Keep them on one line with a horizontal scrollbar? Subtract width from other <div>s equal to the amount you had to add to the small ones? Something else?

Comment: Keep them on one line - but not with a scrollbar. So "Subtract width from other <div>s equal to the amount you had to add to the small ones" sounds like a good solution. But how do I do that 'fairly', like parted over all the bigger divs?